# sed whitespace matching confusion

Tags: sed

```
echo ' 1 2     3  '|sed 's/[[:space:]]*/_/g'
```

I want to see `_1_2_____3__` as the output. Instead, I am seeing `_1_2_3_` as the output. What am I doing wrong??

**EDIT**
The other thing confusing me, which I forgot to put in the above example, is why this:

```
echo ' test1 test2  ' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*/_/g'
```

shows this:

```
_t_e_s_t_1_t_e_s_t_2_
```

How can `[[:space:]]` match between `t` and `e` and `s`...?

Comment: The posted answer already answer that too. * matches **0** or more spaces.

Comment: @Leiaz Hmmm....didn't think of that. So how do I match one or more?

Comment: With + `echo ' test1 test2  ' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/_/g'`

Comment: @Leiaz: Use `'s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/_/g'` for portability.

Comment: @Leiaz Oh yes...been too long since I've studied regex. I do remember now about '+'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you use `*`, meaning it matches 0 or more spaces. So zero or multiple spaces is substitued by one underscore `_`.

Try:

```
$ echo ' 1 2     3  ' | sed 's/[[:space:]]/_/g'
_1_2_____3__
```

Remember that `[[:space:]]` also matches tab, newline, carriage return.

**Note**

- [BREs Matching Multiple Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06)

Answer (score 5):

You've already got an answer but I want to point out that in such simple scenario there is no need to be fancy:

```
$ echo ' 1 2     3  ' | sed 's/ /_/g'
_1_2_____3__
```

If you want to replace only spaces and tabs you can use [ \t] construct as well:

```
$ echo -e " 1\t2     3  " | sed 's/[ \t]/_/g'
_1_2_____3__
```

Answer (score 2):

The question asks explicitly about sed, and it's a very valid question about sed regexp syntax.

But in case the underlying question is about replacing spaces by `_` really, here is an alternative answer using the "right tool for the job" for translating characters, which is `tr`. ([`man tr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tr.1.html)).

The command `tr abc 123` replaces the chars of the first list with the corresponding chars in the second. Thus, `tr ' ' _` replaces space by underscore.

```
$ echo ' 1 2     3  ' | tr ' ' _
_1_2_____3__
```

To show the more general case, including various kinds of whitespace like your example,
here is the output for only translating the normal space character `' '` for comparison:

```
echo ' 1 2     3  x\ny\tz' | tr ' ' _        
_1_2_____3__x
y       z
```

And here is the output when translating all characters of the class :space: to `_`:

```
echo ' 1 2     3  x\ny\tz' | tr '[:space:]' _
_1_2_____3__x_y_z_
```

(Note there is no newline at the end of the output - and there is a `_` after the `z`.)
This can be written explicitly as `tr ' \t\n' _`, which is the short form of `tr ' \t\n' ___`.

```
$ echo ' 1 2     3  x\ny\tz' | tr ' \t\n' _    
_1_2_____3__x_y_z_
```

Comment: I know about `tr`. I will forever regret the example I initially posted. I was specifically wondering how to replace a *sequence* of whitespace with *one* character, even though I did a poor job of explaining that.

Comment: I really did not post my *real* problem at first, just a portion of it. I thought I could figure out the main problem if I could get over the puzzling behavior of my first example.

Comment: Oh, you were clear enough that you ask about sed; But even if the answer is not helpful for you, it may help someone else reading the questions and answers. Someone who uses `sed` like in the answers should at least know that there is a much tool simpler tool for this.